# How can I ask to access permission of audio/sound (not the microphone, but the sound permission) to my site in the navigator

Tags: permissions, navigator

I trying to access the sound permission, but the only thing I found was navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio or video: true }). So I wanna know how can I ask for sound permission, because of the error with lack of interactivity with the user.

Comment: Why do you think you need sound permission? Websites don't require sound permission to play audio.

Comment: google chrome gives me an error when I try to play some sound without at least one user's click (or interation). I tried to solve, nothing worked, but I notice that if I give sound permission it works fine. Anyway, thanks for the answer .